# How to delete a. apk from System/app after being stuck on bootloop?

Tags: android, adb, flashing

So this happened with me another time, and again due to same stuff, I updated my Mx player which was in system/app so I decided to integrate its updated apk to System/app then it started showing "Unfortunately Mx Player have stoppee working" I do this all the time but only Mx player is the one which gave me so much trouble, I renamed it to its package name "com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad.apk" and also set rhe permissions to "-rw-r--r--" and that's where I think I did wrong... 
And I don't know what came over me and I restarted my phoen and its atuck on the black screen after Sony logo so before I fixed it by flashing and wipe my data.
But now I have a lot of data that I didn't have backed up..
Soo can please anyone tell me how can I remove that. Apk from System/app so I that I don't lose my data...
AND I'M DAMN SURE IT IS CAUSED BY THAT APK..
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have root  privilege. Try these form cmd prompt:-

```
adb root
adb remount
adb uninstall <package_name>
adb shell sync
adb reboot
```

Another trick is to access the APK folder in /system/app:-

```
adb root 
adb remount
adb shell
#cd /system/app
# ls // try to rm -rf the apk folder from here
#exit 
adb shell sync
adb reboot
```